# Cannot use console.log() in a module

Tags: javascript, module

I'm trying to understand how to use modules in javascript.

But it seems that if I import a module, then I cannot log anything to console.

Here's my code:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="js/scene.js" type="module"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**scene.js:**

```
class Scene {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Scene created");
    }
}

export default Scene;
```

**main.js:**

```
import { Scene } from './js/scene.js';

var scene = new Scene();

console.log("Hello World");
```

**The Expected Result:**

```
Scene created 
Hello World
```

**The Result I Get:**

```
Nothing (No Result)
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I properly use a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 3 mistakes

- in index.html the first script tag is useless.
- import is relative to script file, not html.
- Scene.js export a default value not a variable named Scene.
  solutions:
- `import Scene from './scene.js';`
  or
- remove default in Scene.js, and `import {Scene} from './scene.js';`

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, I believe that line 1 of `main.js` is throwing an error. In your `index.html` file, you're suggesting that you have a folder named `js` with both javascript modules in it; however, in the `main.js` file, you're suggesting that `scene.js` is at path `js/js/scene.js`.

You probably meant `import { Scene } from './scene.js';`.

---

You should open your browser's console to view any errors.

For example, if you are using Google Chrome, becoming familiar with the Chrome Devtools will be invaluable in allowing you to resolve bugs like this one by yourself in the future.

The Chrome Devtools console will allow you to view errors in your website, which will give you an immediate answer on what is wrong. In addition, setting breakpoints will allow you to step-through each line of code and trace the flow of executed lines of code and the value of variables at each point in time.

Learn more here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Comment: I'm using the Chrome Console and I believe `./js/scene.js` is the correct path. If I changed to `./scene.js` then it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './scene.js' does not provide an export named 'Scene'Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './scene.js' does not provide an export named 'Scene'` in the console.

Comment: We're talking about changing the import path in your `main.js` module, and _not_ in the `index.html` file, right? The code you've provided does not support your comment.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I didn't change `index.html`.

Comment: Interesting. In that case I'd suggest putting breakpoints in the top of both Javascript modules, then step-through and check that the program is executing as you expected. Because there are few lines of code, you should quickly see the issue.